# Cmd 32 bit crashes but 64 bit works

Tags: windows, command-line, crash

I have tried to run a .net core 8 code that worked for me 3 days ago. But now it crashes with error related to access violation

Same code works on another computer

So i tried to look for the cause and figured that my cmd 32 bit crashes with dllhost.exe crashing

It might be after the antivirus update but pausing it did not helped
Maybe installing the core 8 sdk
Was thinking maybe the EDR is blocking, but it did not

Powershell gives same error

the first time the error for dllhost.exe show on event viewer is 06/3/2024 on 10:37 with this log:

```
Faulting application name: DllHost.exe, version: 10.0.22621.1, time stamp: 0x05e70ed3
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.22621.3085, time stamp: 0x9c05761b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000a76ae
Faulting process id: 0x0x13504
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA6FA09BB91C5C
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\DllHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
Report Id: 2bdfaa34-7b82-44aa-8a97-750a0f4c6c1c
Faulting package full name: EsetContextMenu_11.0.2032.0_neutral__f55j32bkf4yvt
Faulting package-relative application ID: ESET
```

the first error before that is this one:

> The program explorer.exe version 10.0.22621.3155 stopped interacting
> with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the
> problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and
> Maintenance control panel.

How can that be checked, fixed without installing the whole computer?

And what could cause it

Comment: What error messages do you get and what do they say? What "access violation" message and dllhost errors do you actually see? Why do you believe this might be antivirus related? Have you had trouble with this particular machine in the past?  When including error messages it is helpful to show the full text of the message. You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Process exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005)

Comment: Faulting application name dllhost.exe

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc Dism did not help finished successfully and still can't run sfc /scannow - i get Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service. the service is started and running

Comment: You need a stronger method for ensuring that Windows is in a consistent state - [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Answer (score -1):

It's ESET.   It's been causing issues for several days now.   Try disabling HIPS detection within ESET and reboot.   Or more crudely uninstall ESET temporarily to prove.   You may also find that opening command prompt, it crashes after a few seconds, which I see you did.

Comment: Do you have any sources that confirm your claim that it is ESET? Besides the `Faulting package-relative application ID: ESET` is there some authoritative source on the internet confirming this issue?

Comment: it was ESET! their DEEP INSPECTION

Answer (score -1):

Had very similar issue with this error code, and yes, it was ESET, the DEEP BEHAVIORAL INSPECTION under the HIPS toggle. Disable it and everything will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).